# ASP.NET XML Control DocumentContent Property

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I am using ASP.NET XML control and on Page Load event I am updating its DocumentContent property but the problem is data isn't being shown. The control is empty on page load.

```
xmlDIMenuSource.DocumentContent = "<Menu><Parent ID="1" Name="Order" SortOrder="1"><Child ID="21" Name="Create an Order" URL="../Order/OrderCapturingv4.aspx?Action=new" SortOrder="1" /><Child ID="32" Name="Import a Style" URL="../Order/OrderCapturingv4.aspx?Action=import" SortOrder="2" /></Menu>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use valid XML.  Plus, if this is VB.Net, you do not need the semi-colon at the end of the expression.  Try this...

```
xmlDIMenuSource.DocumentContent = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><Menu><Parent ID="1" Name="Order" SortOrder="1"><Child ID="21" Name="Create an Order" URL="../Order/OrderCapturingv4.aspx?Action=new" SortOrder="1" /><Child ID="32" Name="Import a Style" URL="../Order/OrderCapturingv4.aspx?Action=import" SortOrder="2" /></Parent></Menu>"
```